# Calculate occurance of each character in a string without using count in C++

Tags: c++, string, unique

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void calc(string s){
    for(int i = 0;i < s.size();++i){
        int count = 1;
        for(int j = i + 1;j <s.size();++j){
            if(s[i] == s[j]){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        cout << s[i] <<"(" << count << ")" << " ";
    }

}


int main(){
    string str;
    while(cin >> str){
        calc(str);
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, except that I want to iterate through unique characters in string and I don't know how to implement this.
Can you help me with it?

Comment: This code doesn't even attempt to do that does it?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils actually, it does. But it iterates through the whole string, but I want to iterate through unique characters of string

Comment: You are looking for a count of each character or a count of how many unique characters there are in the string? Your wording is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. Here are a few suggestions:

1. Modify the code you have written so that before you count up how many times a character appears after the current character, you first scan over the characters before you in the string to see if any of them match. If so, skip the current character.
2. Every time you find a character that matches the current character, replace it with a copy of the first character in the string. Then, whenever you visit a character in the string that isn't in the first position, check if it matches the first character in the string. If so, you've already scanned it. If not, count up its occurrences.
3. Maintain an auxiliary data structure (an array, a hash table, etc.) mapping characters to their frequencies. Fill in the table by doing one pass over the original string, then iterate over the table, which has unique keys, to print everything out.
4. Sort the string. Counting how many times each character occurs then boils down to finding the length of each consecutive run of characters in the string.

Option (1) is good if you can't modify the original string and if you're not allowed to use other data structures. Option (2) has excellent time and space requirements if you're allowed to modify the original string. Option (3) is likely the easiest to code up, but uses a bit more space than other approaches. Option (4) is also very easy to code up and, if you use something like heapsort, has good memory usage but is still asymptotically slower than option (2).

Comment: Thank you, I used your 2 advice and it works!
Actually I know how tto code it in Python(it's very easy), but I am new to C++ and the style is completely different:) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you maintain an auxillary array of 26 length, initialize it to 0 and then increment the corresponding index's value by 1 everytime you encounter a character?

Pseudocode:

```
auxArray[26] = [0] // 26 length array initialized to zero
for character in string: // loop through every character in the string
    auxArray[character - 'a']++; //increment the corresponding index value by 1

print auxArray //print the entire array. [0] will give you count of 'a', and [25] will give you count of 'z'
```

This is assuming that you have a character String from 'a' to 'z' (All lower case).

In the case where we have an uppercase-lowercase mixture of characters as well, you might similar stuff but instead use an array of 128. In this case, you won't have to subtract `'a'` as it was being done to accommodate the indexes with the chars.

```
auxArray[128] = [0]
for character in string:
    auxArray[character]++;

for index in auxArray:
    print(((char)index) + " Count is " + auxArray[index])
```

Comment: You can take length 52 in that case? or 62? or worst case, you can take an array of length 128 for ASCII?

Comment: @RetiredNinja ok let me do it :p

Comment: @RetiredNinja Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with `std::map`:

```
std::map<char,int> count;

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    count[s[i]]++;
for (auto iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); ++iter)
    std::cout << iter->first << “: “ << iter->second << ‘\n’;
```

Not tested, sorry.